# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, at Array.forEach

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-js, office-addins

When I press the button to display the task pane, I am seeing the following error message in the console window which I cannot remove or explain ?

```
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
at t (word-web-16.00.js:26)
at word-web-16.00.js:26
at Office.js:46
at Array.forEach ()
at d (Office.js:46)
at Office.js:46
```

[image]

Steps to Reproduce - Side load the TypeScript add-in into Word Online and press the Button to display the task pane.

The task pane is displayed but why is this error message appearing.

This error message might have always been there, not sure.
I have tried all the following URLs and the message is consist.

```
src="appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/Office.js"
src="appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js"
src="appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/Office.js"
```

This appears in Word Online
Windows 10 64 bit and Office 64 bit
Browser - Microsoft Edge, Version 88.0.705.68 (Official build) (64-bit)

The following repository contains the project (only 5 files):
https://github.com/OfficeAddins/undefined

This issue was logged on github but no-one has replied yet:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using this using lowercase o when referencing the office.js url -
src="appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js"

This could be due to a case sensitive string comparison bug, which we will fix. You should be able to workaround it by using the lowercase office.js.

Comment: Thank you so much Jay !!!
Yes, the error message has disappeared !!